# Does protocol buffers support lightweight reference serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers

Suppose a class like this:

```
class Person {
  public string Name;
  public Person Parent;
}
```

Now you create two objects:

```
...
Person mike = new Person("Mike");
Person jack = new Person("Jack");
jack.Parent = mike;
List<Person> family = new List<Person>();
people.Add(mike);
people.Add(jack);
...
```

Will the string "Mike" serialized once (maintaining) a unique reference to object mike and then resolving it, or will be serialized twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer here is "it depends". The protobuf specification does not include any object identifiers / re-use, so *normally* (and by default) this would be a tree serialization, and the data would be duplicated.

We can examine this by using protobuf-net with *all the default behaviours*:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person mike = new Person { Name = "Mike" };
        Person jack = new Person { Name = "Jack" };
        jack.Parent = mike;
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(mike);
        people.Add(jack);

        var cloneOfEverything = Serializer.DeepClone(people);

        var newMike = cloneOfEverything.Single(x => x.Name == "Mike");
        var newJack = cloneOfEverything.Single(x => x.Name == "Jack");
        Console.WriteLine(jack.Parent.Name); // writes Miks as expected

        bool areSamePersonObject = ReferenceEquals(newMike, newJack.Parent);
        // False ^^^

        bool areSameStringInstance = ReferenceEquals(
            newMike.Name, newJack.Parent.Name);
        // True ^^^
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Person Parent;
}
```

Observations:

- Jack's parent is correctly called Mike
- but it is a different object instance that just looks identical
- the `string` is the same instance - as an implementation detail, protobuf-net includes code that spots the same UTF-8 chunk in the data, and re-uses the same `string` instance to avoid allocations - but the data was included twice in the binary
- for info, the above tree takes 24 bytes

We can also see this by investigating what happens here:

```
Person mike = new Person { Name = "Mike" };
mike.Parent = mike;
var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(mike);
```

Because it is writing as a tree, it errors with:

> Possible recursion detected (offset: 1 level(s)): Person

However! As libary-specific implementation details, protobuf-net includes lots of knobs and dials that you can turn. One of these relates to object identity. We can toggle `Person` to act with reference identity:

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault=true)]
class Person {...}
```

This ***changes the data in the binary*** (to include additional markers), and as a consequence - now the same lines work:

```
Person mike = new Person { Name = "Mike" };
mike.Parent = mike;
var clone = Serializer.DeepClone(mike);
bool areSamePersonObject = ReferenceEquals(clone, clone.Parent);
// ^^^ true
```

Note that this uses implementation-specific details, and may confuse other implementations.

`AsReferenceDefault` here states that `Person` should be treated as a reference whenever it is seen; for more granular control, `[ProtoMember]` also includes an `AsReference` object which can be used individually. A quick check, however, seems to indicate that it is **not** currently working properly with `List<Person>` - I will need to investigate that. There may be a good reason, but I can't think of one currently, and I suspect that is a bug.

`AsReference` can also be included on `string` members to avoid writing the same string repeatedly - although note that in this case it is probably cheaper to write `"Mike"` twice! This option would be useful when the same `string` is repeated *lots* of times. Despite the name, when working with `string`, `AsReference` is interpreted as "string equality", not "reference equality".

Comment: Understood. So the short answer is "not normally", because I suppose that with complex objects the things could change a lot ... right?

Comment: The short answer is "not normally", but the reason for that is much simpler: *because that isn't what the specification says to do*